# Draw geom_hline not across entire plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I make a `geom_hline` not to be shown across the entire plot?

```
d=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,4,6,7,9), y=c(9,3,7,1,8,4,5,6))
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=d, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=5.375, color="red")
```

Produces:

[image]

How do I let `geom_hline` go from, for example, 2.6 until 4.2?

Comment: just use geom_line() instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use geom_segment:

```
d=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,4,6,7,9), y=c(9,3,7,1,8,4,5,6))
ggplot() +
geom_point(data=d, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_segment(aes(x=2,xend=4.2,y=5.375,yend=5.375),color="red")
```

[image]