# Plot per-group means over geom_bar w

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with three columns: a factor (representing here a chapter in a book), a numerical ID (representing where the sentence occurs in the book), and a value (representing the number of words in the book). It looks something like this:

```r
sentence.length
# A tibble: 5,368 x 3
   Chapter    ID Length
   <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1           1    294
 2 1           2     19
 3 1           3     77
 4 1           4     57
 5 1           5     18
 6 1           6     18
 7 1           7     27
 8 1           8     56
 9 1           9     32
10 1          10     25
# ... with 5,358 more rows
```

I have a plot that is very close to what I want.

```r
ggplot(data,aes(x=ID,y=Length,fill=Chapter)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image: A ggplot plot]

What I'd like to add is, over every group, is a horizontal line representing the mean of that group.

This code, modified from another question, gets me close

```r
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, aes(x = 1, yintercept = ..y.., group = Chapter), geom = "hline")
```

But the lines extend across the entire plot; is there a way to plot that mean line only over the relevant portion of the plot? I suspect the issue here is that my data happens to be ordered such that a `group` corresponds to a continuous part of the plot; but there is nothing in the aesthetics of the plot itself to require this.

An even closer approach is to use not `stat_summary` but `geom_smooth`; `geom_smooth(method='lm',se=FALSE)` gets me really close. But rather than a linear regression, I really just want the mean for the group (here, the per-chapter sentence length mean).

[image: ggplot using geom_smooth]

Is there a better/simpler approach?

Comment: The geom_segment solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207564/draw-geom-hline-not-across-entire-plot might be what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks @emily-kothe; I hand't seen that, and geom_segment is key! The solution below combines it with tools from wrapr to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the simplest way to do this, but it works:

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wrapr)

df %.>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(
    x = ID,
    y = Length,
    fill = Chapter
  )) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_segment(data = group_by(., Chapter) %>%
    summarise(
      mean_len = mean(Length),
      min_id = min(ID),
      max_id = max(ID)
    ),
    aes(
      x = min_id,
      xend = max_id,
      y = mean_len,
      yend = mean_len
    ),
    color = 'steelblue',
    size = 1.2
  )
```

With `%.>%` pipe you can pass down `df` to summarise it in `geom_segment` function. You can access `df` after `%.>%` by `.`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Even if it isn't the *simplest*, it definitely is clear, well-expressed, and avoids the ridiculous calculating each mean by hand jiggery-pokery that I was getting into.